# Place holder list item like facebook for content loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display list item placeholder while content loading like: Faceook. How can I achieve that ?[image]

Comment: please check this library :
https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android

Answer (score 7):

There is no library for Android for that as far as I know , I could write one , but I am Lazy :)

So what I do for now is just using this nice [Schimering effect](http://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/) from facebook over a simple view with gray background .

```
    <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/gallery_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

That works for me ...

Answer (score 4):

There is now a new library called [`ShimmerRecyclerview`](https://github.com/sharish/ShimmerRecyclerView) which is based from the [`Facebook Shimmer`](http://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/)

To use it, you define your xml recyclerview like this:

```
<com.cooltechworks.views.shimmer.ShimmerRecyclerView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/shimmer_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:demo_child_count="10"
        app:demo_grid_child_count="2"
        app:demo_layout="@layout/layout_demo_grid"
        app:demo_layout_manager_type="grid"
        />
```

`demo_layout` attribute is where your template placeholder placed.

To show the shimmering layout, call:

```
shimmerRecycler.showShimmerAdapter();
```

And to hide it:

```
shimmerRecycler.hideShimmerAdapter();
```

Comment: where do you call hide shimmer ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Skeleton](https://github.com/rasoulmiri/Skeleton) esay.

see this [link](https://github.com/rasoulmiri/Skeleton/tree/master/sample) for sample project.

see this [link](http://sample%20APK) for apk project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5890

you can customize your shimmer item for recyclerview.